# Is it possible to set the description of an Rancher stack with rancher-compose.yml?

Tags: configuration, rancher

Is it somehow possible to set the description of the a rancher stack (in this picture the grey Rabbitmq).
[image: picture of an stack with description]

I know, I can set this by editing the stack, but i want to set it with the rancher-compose.yml file.
[image: editing the stack]

I haven't find anything for this in the documentation

Comment: I know that it's somehow possible to do it with the API, but I just want to do it with a simple single line in the `rancher-compose.yml` or in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: There's a long standing post on GitHub for this. No answers yet, but adding here as a comment in case that situation changes. https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/5575